# Responsiveness with aurelia-ui-virtualization

Tags: aurelia

Any of you guys know if there is some responsiveness support planned? It seems like the library (i know that it is still a beta) have some issues calculating the height of rows. Additionally, it does not support multi-height within rows, is this featured planned?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try aurelia-virtual-scroll. This will receive breakpoints as parameters so you can configure different heights in different resolutions. Check the readme.md documentation.